# Is there a way to integrate mongo db in an offline desktop app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, electron

I have recently knew about electron npm module and I've found out it's really useful for creating a desktop app using node.js. I already know how to setup the mongo db on the local machine and get connected to it but, I was wondering if there is a way to integrate mongo db within the offline desktop application itself?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/lp/contact/partner/oem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are willing to install MongoDB server on each desktop client.

There is also MongoDB Mobile, but it's available only for Android and iOS https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/mongodb-mobile

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate MongoDB into a desktop app, you would pretty much have to either install Mongo onto the user's machine with the app. On the other hand, there are databases similar to Mongo that are designed to be embedded within an app such as CouchDB but Mongo doesn't provide a way of embedding it into an application without contacting them.